# ApplePay option not available on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator, applepay

- I am running a iPhone 6 Plus simulator with iOS 10.1
- I have pressed `Authorized Apple Pay` (if that matters).
- `General> Language & Region > Region` is set to US and language is set to `EN-US`.
- There is no ApplePay/Wallet setting in the Settings app.
- `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:` returns `YES`.
- `[[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc]
          initWithPaymentRequest:request];` with a valid request with proper currency and items returns nil everytime.
- I have tried restarting the simulator.
- I have a proper merchant ID setup on developer.apple.com and the required configuration in the entitlements.

It is suppose to work on the simulator for iPhone. I am not sure where the problem is. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there something obvious I am missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have the same problem. i implemented apple pay with stripe using swift. I run the program it is works well in simulators but not in real iphone device? Why ? do you know the reason please help me.